# Browser Overlay for Data Entry: Client or Server Side?

Tags: ajax, django, proxy

I am developing a Django app that functions basically as a data entry tool for websites.  The use case has a trusted user or paid technician browsing the web.  As they browse they enter data into an overlaid bar similar to what you see on many proxy websites, but containing a form that allows user to write metadata about the website (in this case, training classification data for an ML algorithm) and submit it to my app.

See http://hidemyass.com/proxy/ for an example of a proxy website that inserts an overlay into browsed sites.

I have heard conflicting suggestions on how to approach this.

### Serve Websites as Proxy

Pipe all url requests through the django app with something like http://httpproxy.yvandermeer.net/, and rewrite the responses to include the header.

**Pros**

- I can process the responses with sexy scientific libraries like the NLTK
- AJAX-free failover.  Users can submit human data (albeit with more of a hassle) without the need to submit computed data.

**Cons**

- Greatly increased traffic.  Now my webapp has to retrieve all websites and upload them to the user.
- Some websites might block proxy requests.  My intention is to deploy this on Heroku, but they might frown on an app that generates so many requests.

### User Browses in an iFrame

The overlay is separated from the content by an iFrame, and I use javascript to inform the overlay on the page that is currently being browsed

**Pros**

- Distributed Computing.  User machines are used to make requests and do any necessary computations.  The server is no longer a bottleneck.
- Tighter Ajax integration.  I can just post a JSON object representative of my entire Model.

**Cons**

- iframes weren't really designed for full-scale browsing.  Some websites force themselves out of iframes, and I worry that it won't be a reliable method of browsing.
- I don't get to use all those sexy python libraries.  My language processing will have to be done in javascript.

### Question

I've never done anything like this before.  I'm pretty new to all the tools involved, and seriously having trouble choosing between the two very different approaches.

**Which method would you suggest?  Why?  Are there any considerations I have missed?**

Answer (score 0):

OKFN's annotator provides imho a good basis for what you are trying to accomplish http://okfn.github.com/annotator/